# I need to drive an LED on a small battery for 400+ hours. Ideal setup for efficiency?

Tags: led, batteries, pwm, efficiency

Now I'm nowhere near en expert in this field. I hardly know what the terms mean. However, I have very limited time to design a product of which requires some knowledge of electrical engineering, I've looked around and asked around and all I get is gibberish in response, none of it is parsable for me. I'm gonna need an ELI5 (Explain Like I'm Five). Here's my situation.

1. I am designing a wireless, battery-operated Christmas light, using a white LED.
2. It needs to be in a relatively small package, so the battery would ideally be smaller than or around the size of a AAA. (I know, I'm asking for a lot here.)
3. It needs to last the whole season before recharging, so about a month (on certain limits, keep reading.)
4. The light will turn off during night time to conserve battery. The user can customize the hours it will be on for, but as an example let's say from 07:00 to 22:00
5. The light will flash, so for example be on for 1 second and then off for the next 3 seconds. This produces the effect of the tree being lit up by all of the lights while quadrupling the life of the battery.
6. I've heard about something called a PWM - this could also be used to extend the life of the battery while maintaining perceived brightness. I don't know what it is or how to use it, or what numbers to plug in to obtain optimal efficiency.
7. My father also recommended me a resonant circuit, of which I also have no knowledge.

How might I be able to solve this? Simply what parts do I need and what do I do with them to get the goal achieved?

Edit:

The project is for a school assignment.

If the goal as mentioned above is not achievable, what compromises must I make?

I came here because it's a forum for the distribution of knowledge, I didn't expect so many negative responses. I know I'm asking a lot but take it easy. This isn't my specialty.

Comment: "The user can customise the hours it's on for", does that mean you need to power a microcontroller too?

Comment: It's ten months till xmas, why the rush?

Comment: *I'm gonna need an ELI5* I have no idea what you mean. <long story> so basically you have no clue how to do this. To explain everything you need to know, uhm do you have a couple of weeks for an intense course? I don't either! In my opinion the distance between **your knowledge** and the knowledge **you need** is simply too large. So voting as too broad. *My father also recommended me a resonant circuit* next time ask him to elaborate on that, persoanbnly I see no reason for a "resonant circuit". This begs the question why **you** were choosen for this task.

Comment: With all due respect, you want to "design" a circuit where obviously you have no idea whatsoever what you are talking about. Does it seem reasonably for you to charge anybody for your "work"? OK, I have an idea. A neighbour has to go a heart bypass operation and I want to do it. Here I have a knife and a bit of alcohol. I heard you have to put the patient to sleep, so maybe I will give him some pills. And my father talked about something like EKG but have no idea what it is.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has clearly no clue about what is talking about and hasn't got the skills needed to understand the topic at its most basic level.

Comment: What the heck is a ELI5?

Comment: I'm not going to vote to close this only so we can leave this question around for a good laugh, and as as a example of *"Don't be like that guy."*.

Comment: ELI5 = Explain Like I'm Five

Comment: I wouldn't even attempt explaining any of this to a 5 year old.

Comment: Re, "PWM - could also be used to extend the life of the battery while maintaining perceived brightness."  In a word, No.  The purpose of PWM is to _reduce_ the perceived brightness.  Extended battery life is a side benefit of that.

Comment: Have a look at https://hackaday.io/project/11864-tritiled - those are very dim but the technique is what you need.

Comment: This forum will never replace school.  Dont they teach physics in high school?  Lets see how much energy is in  a battery and how much do you need?  The rest is instructable PIC chip programming and with sensors but using a CR123A battery.

Comment: For what it's worth, 7 is probably a circuit known as a "Joule thief" - Google it.

Comment: I can't believe some people come to forums like this without the basic knowledge of common internet phrases like ELI5. The nerve!

Comment: @pjc50 Consider expanding that comment into an answer, since it's actually constructive and polite.

Comment: @RussellBorogove Please, read the help center: ***this is not a general electronic forum***. The netiquette here doesn't follow common internet jargon. We don't expect users to be expert in leetspeech or whatever. On the contrary, we strictly *require* standard English in writing both questions and answers. An excess of "internettisms" is shun over. So, although no one will complain about some "IANAL" or "TL;TD" abbreviations, we don't require any user to know them. On the contrary, we require users to show effort, both in asking and in answering a question. We are not a free design center.

Comment: I'm French. I had no idea what ELI5 was, so I double clicked and then clicked on "google this", and first result is the answer. While I agree the OP should not have used this abbreviation and expect us to know what the hell it meant, I'm still cool for learning this totally useless nugget of English vocabulary.

Comment: Erik, you got shot down because you did not mention this was a classroom exercise. Here, we often get people who come and ask the community to do their job for them (a job they are being paid for... mind you...) and these people are nuked. Students asking for people to do their homework for them without effort are also nuked. BUT we also get students facing difficult, nonsensical, sometimes impossible or badly specified questions from their clueless teachers. This is occasional. Plain idiots are more frequent. Your mistake was not making it easy for us to know in which category you were.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First thing to check is feasibility, in order to avoid expensive mistake, like SOLAR FRICKEN ROADWAYS, for example.

One alkaline AA battery contains about 4 Wh (watt-hours) of energy if your circuit can drain it fully.

This means if you want it to last for 400 hours the average power draw of the circuit should be less than 4Wh/400h = 0.01W.

To light a white LED we need a boost converter, let's count 80% efficiency, let's neglect the power for control circuits, and light the LED with a duty cycle of 25%.

LED power = 0.01W / 25% * 80% = 0.032W

This means we can afford 10mA current to light the LED. It's doable, but it won't be very bright.

A smaller AAA battery has 3x less capacity, so the same calculation leaves us with 3x less current. It won't work.

Better not go wireless then!

Or, since you lack the knowedge and skills, you can go low-tech: purchase bicycle blinkies for about $2 each, and restyle the enclosure to your needs. Or go [chinese](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/20pcs-lot-Wireless-Remote-Controller-Cake-Party-Decoration-Small-Battery-Operated-Waterproof-Micro-Mini-LED-Lights/32755587507.html?spm=a2g0w.search0104.3.87.6e5f795aFra1Jb&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_5_10152_10151_10065_10344_10068_10342_10343_10340_10341_10084_10083_10618_10305_10630_10304_10307_10306_10302_10313_10059_10184_10534_100031_10629_10103_10626_10625_10624_10623_10622_10621_10620_10142,searchweb201603_1,ppcSwitch_5&algo_expid=5dd154ae-2e36-4242-b41f-736c171d800f-13&algo_pvid=5dd154ae-2e36-4242-b41f-736c171d800f&transAbTest=ae803_5&priceBeautifyAB=0).

Comment: I agree. though the OP did not actually say he was using a AAA, just he wanted it that physical size. A different tech rechargeable battery may be within range. Still, jumping in the deep end for this OP though.

Comment: Yeah, but "you fail hard due to not clearing up extremely blurry specifications and lack of research" is an extremely valuable engineering lesson for OP. The best engineering lesson I got was doing an internship in a company where the design engineer was a total idiot, and my internship was doing board level repair on their shitty products that went poof when someone looked at them wrong. The repair techs hated the engineering dept with passionate rage. The whole company was a dumpster fire. Best learning experience ever. Truly humbling LOL.

Answer (score 8):

> nowhere near en expert ... I have very limited time ... design a product ... requires electrical engineering ... I've heard about something called a PWM ... asked around ... gibberish ... none of it is parsable

You are in **way** over your head.  There are issues here from fundamental physics to detailed electrical engineering.  We can't and won't design a whole product for you here, and we can't teach you the equivalent of a college degree in electrical engineering here either.

Go hire someone, possibly as a consultant.  If you don't have money for that, then forget about the whole thing.

If you do get a consultant, here is some advice.  Tell them what you want the product to do, NOT how you think it should do it.  Separate requirements from implementation.  Then actually *listen* when they tell you certain things aren't possible.  Instead of arguing that they must be since you need them to be, ask what tradeoffs you can get.  At the end of that, you have to decide whether you still have a product with the tradeoffs physics and available technology force you to make.

Good engineering is expensive.  Bad engineering is much more expensive and can sink your company.

Comment: I'm not starting a company, what I forgot to include in this question was that it's for a school project. My original project was going to be a game coded in Unity, but that proved too time-consuming for the constraints given to me by my teacher. So I swapped to this idea, that one could get rid of the hassle of wired Christmas lights by making them battery powered. I wrote up diagrams and everything, but on further research I found that it would be very difficult to make the lights last long enough for an entire christmas season. I merely ask, in basic terms, how might i go about doing it?

Comment: @ErikAlexanderEklof - in basic terms: magic. Because physics can't help you here.

Comment: +1 for "Good engineering is expensive. Bad engineering is much more expensive and can sink your company." well that and it's a darn good answer :)